# "Error: unrecognized arguments" when I run a python script on a CMake file

Tags: cmake

I am trying to run a python script on a cmake file but I get this error message:

```
bin2h.py: error: unrecognized arguments:> .../MainWindow.xaml.bin.h
```

there is the code in the CMake file:

```
execute_process (COMMAND python ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin2h.py "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/MainWindow.xaml" > "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/MainWindow.xaml.bin.h")
```

I don't know why exactly that error appears. When I run the the script in the terminal works fine.

There is the example in the terminal:

```
python bin2h.py MainWindow.xaml > MainWindow.xaml.bin.h
```

And I try running the script with the full path of the files and it works fine.

PS: Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/execute_process.html
>
> CMake executes the child process using operating system APIs directly.
> All arguments are passed VERBATIM to the child process. No
> intermediate shell is used, so shell operators such as > are treated
> as normal arguments. (Use the INPUT_*, OUTPUT_*, and ERROR_* options
> to redirect stdin, stdout, and stderr.)

In other words, you can't use ">" redirection with execute_process() like you're doing.